# ELIF statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have done the program, but I keep getting an invalid syntax at the close of main and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get the elif to get the multiple of the larger number, and to indicate how many times the smaller integer divides into the larger. Also, on my else statement, the smaller integer is not a multiple of the larger one, the program would show the whole number quotient and remainder when the larger is divided by the smaller integer. Code below:

```
def main():
    num1 = int(input('Enter any numbers greater than 2:'))
    num2 = int(input('Enter any number less than num1:'))
    if num2 >= num1:
        print("Bad_Input.Try_Again")
    elif num1 % num2 == 0:
        quotient = num1 / num2
        print(quotient)
    else:
        print(num1 / num2)
        print(num1 % num2)
        print(num1,'divides by',num2,'=','and remainder',divmod(num1 / num2)

main()
```

Can anyone tell me why I keep getting an Invalid syntax error when trying to execute the program.

Comment: Need one closing bracket after `divmod(num1 / num2)`

Comment: is this the exact indentation you have?

Answer (score 1):

Your code was missing a closing bracket and the divmod function an argument:

```
print(num1,'divides by',num2,'=','and remainder',divmod(num1 / num2)
```

should have been

```
print(num1,'divides by',num2,'=','and remainder',divmod(num1, num2))
```

The full code:

```
def main():
    num1 = int(input('Enter any numbers greater than 2:'))
    num2 = int(input('Enter any number less than num1:'))
    if num2 >= num1:
        print("Bad_Input.Try_Again")
    elif num1 % num2 == 0:
        quotient = num1 / num2
        print(quotient)
    else:
        print(num1 / num2)
        print(num1 % num2)
        print(num1,'divides by',num2,'=','and remainder',divmod(num1, num2))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(num1,'divides by',num2,'=','and remainder',divmod(num1 / num2)
```

should be

```
print(num1,'divides by',num2,'=','and remainder',divmod(num1, num2))
```

**notice the missing last closing bracket**. Because of this, when the python interpreter reads the file, it thinks that the next `main()` statement is also part of the `print` statement.

Comment: i added the bracket at the end and when i ran the else statement i got the error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Darlene\Desktop\chapter 3 testing round 2.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Darlene\Desktop\chapter 3 testing round 2.py", line 12, in main
    print(num1,'divides by',num2,'=','and remainder',divmod(num1 / num2))
TypeError: divmod expected 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: @DarlenePorter You are basically missing an argument, your code should have been divmod(num1, num2)

Comment: edited my answer, it's actually divmod(num1, num2)

Comment: i've tried several different ways, and i am still not getting the output i need which is on the elif, example: 9 divides evenly into 72 exactly 8 times, and for the else example, 57 divided by 16 = 3 and remainder 9.  i have been working on something this simple for a week and cannot get that output.  on the elif i am getting a float.

Comment: @darleneporter You need integer division `//`  since `/` always gives a float even when dividing integers in Python 3.